# Abstracting connection errors

Tags: c#, connection, abstraction

I've got an interface called IConnection

```
public interface IConnection
{

    bool IsConnected { get; }
    Task ConnectAsync(IEndPoint remoteEP);
    Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] data, int offset, int size);
    Task<int> ReceiveAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size);
    void Disconnect();
    void Close();

    event EventHandler<DisconnectedEventArgs> Disconnected;

}
```

It is implemented by two different types of connection - a Socket based connection class and an HTTP based connection class. I also want the option of adding other connection types in future.

When initiating a connection in my main ChatClient class I will check the user's configuration and then depending on what the user prefers, will create a SocketConnection or an HTTPConnection. From that point onward I only refer to the connection using it's IConnection interface.

The IConnection class has a Disconnected event which is raised when the user calls Disconnect, or when some unexpected connection error occurs. The DisconnectedEventArgs will contain information about what caused that disconnect to occur.

What I'm wondering is, how do I abstract the different types of errors?

A socket can experience many different error conditions which would cause it to disconnect, including but not limited to -

- Remote side initiated a graceful disconnect (ie.. Read returns 0)
- A read/write throws a SocketException with flag SocketError.ConnectionAborted
- A read/write throws a SocketException with flag SocketError.NetworkReset

An http connection can also experience many different error conditions, for example -

- A failure to poll the remote server -- eg.. host suddenly disappears
- HTTP authentication credentials are rejected

How do I combine all of the possible errors for a socket and all the possible errors for an http connection into a single type?

Do I use an enum containing values for all of the possible errors?

Do I have a simple error code and a description of the error?

And how many of the many many socket error conditions am I supposed to handle? Only the ones I expect to encounter? Or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Why not have `DisconnectEventArgs` contain a `public Exception Error { get; set; }`.  `Error` is null when `Disconnect` is called normally, otherwise it contains a Socket or Http exception.

Comment: I have considered this, but I feel this forces the user code to know all of the underlying connection types, so every time a new connection type is added the user code has to be refactored. Also, do you know of any production code which does something like this? Anything in the .NET framework? I like to follow best practices.

Comment: The "user code" should not care about the type of error.  All it needs to know is that some error occurred and then report it to the user.

Comment: But if each type of exception (SocketException, HttpConnectionException) contains specific information, then in user land that exception is going to need to be cast to the different types of exceptions and then examined for more detailed information to present to the user. The only other way is to present it to the user by calling ToString() on the exception, and as I understand it, that method is only supposed to be used by the programmer, and not shown to the user.

Comment: Each exception has a `Message`, just show that to the user. Possible prefix with "Unable to complete 'operation' because ..."

Comment: It was my understanding that the Message was not intended for the user, and exists only for the programmer.

Comment: I've been showing it to users for the past 10 years.  You could never predetermine all the exceptions and errors associated with network communications.